# AltGr not working properly on VMware

Tags: keyboard, vmware, keyboard-layout, localization, fedora-18

I'm working on Fedora 18 on a VMware VM. Until yesterday my keyboard was OK, but I was trying with my boss to get the extended ASCII code activating the composed keys with so many ways (and all of them failed). The thing is that now I don't need it and while I was programming I found the next problem: I can't type the "**{**". (NOTE: I'm using a Spanish keyboard:
[image: Spanish keyboard]
so I need the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to type "{" and "}".)

The thing is that I've undone everything I touched yesterday, BUT there was a short time that my boss touched my PC and I wasn't in front of it and today he is out so I can't ask him what did.

If I try to type "}" it works (so <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is working in some way), BUT if I try to type "{" then it prints a bold tile " **´** " so I can't open any loop which is a very annoying problem.
I've see some other posts like this: [Alt-Gr key is not working in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/432957/309110)
cause I know that my boss deleted the English option that was there (by default) and left the Spanish one alone. I've set two more English options: US International with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and US international with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (alternative), but the result is the same (I've applied the changes and reset the computer). And now I don't know what else can I try to fix that problem, so any idea or hint would be very appreciated.

I also looked at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to see if it is as before and it seems that is OK.

```
 This file was generated by the Anaconda installer
 Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "anaconda-keyboard"
     MatchIsKeyboard    "on"
     Option "XkbLayout" "es,us"
     Option "XkbVariant"    "cat,"
     Option "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
 EndSection
```